# New textfile every time run with Python

Tags: python

How can I create a new text file every time I run the following program? I want to collect data, every 5 secs, but I don't want to overwrite the first text file.  I use also a `time.sleep(5)` function.

```
fobj_out = open("Tabelle.txt", "w")                                 
fobj_out.write("Orte chron.: [Höhe in m, Temp. in °C, rel. Feuchte in %, Niederschlag in mm, Sonnenschein in %]\n")

for key in sorted(unserdictionary.iterkeys()):                      
    print("%s: %s" % (key, unserdictionary[key]))                   
    fobj_out.write("%s: %s\n" % (key, unserdictionary[key]))
fobj_out.close
```

Is there a simple way?

Comment: Create a file and append the current time to the filename. That way you will have a different filename everytime

Comment: You can keep using a single file when you *append* to it instead of overwriting its contents entirely (open with `'a'` instead of `'w'`).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current time, and append it to the file name.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
actual_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", gmtime())

fobj_out = open("Tabelle - " + str(actual_time) + ".txt", "w")                                 
fobj_out.write("Orte chron.: [Höhe in m, Temp. in °C, rel. Feuchte in %, Niederschlag in mm, Sonnenschein in %]\n")

for key in sorted(unserdictionary.iterkeys()):                      
    print("%s: %s" % (key, unserdictionary[key]))                   
    fobj_out.write("%s: %s\n" % (key, unserdictionary[key]))
fobj_out.close
```

You will get outputs as follows:

```
Tabelle - 2015-01-01 21-15-13.txt
Tabelle - 2015-01-01 21-20-13.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what we thought but I tried it out, I got this error: line 96, in <module> fobj_out = open("Tabelle - " + str(actual_time) + ".txt", "w") IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'Tabelle - 2015-06-17 09:13:04.txt'

Comment: @Hadouken Sorry, it was due to the `:` of the time. Please, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time and then append that to the filename , you can use `time` module to get the time. Code would be like -

```
from time import time 
s = str(round(time() * 1000))
fobj_out = open("Tabelle" + s + ".txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the file already exists and then either create it or just append to the already existing file.

```
import os.path

if(os.path.isfile("Tabelle.txt")):
    obj_out = open("Tabelle.txt", "a")   # Append to the file
else:
    obj_out = open("Tabelle.txt", "w")   # create the file

# do the rest here....
```

Comment: Using `open` with `'a'` will also create the file, so there is no need for checking whether the file exists.